# OpenSSL: How to export RSA keys from a RSA structure?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography

I want to export RSA keypair which is generated via RSA_generate_key_ex from a RSA struct:

Are there any ways to export it into a c char array instead of a file?

So far I only know about PEM_write_RSAPublicKey and PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey, but they export key to a file, not array.

```
int             ret = 0;
RSA             *r = NULL;
BIGNUM          *bne = NULL;

bne = BN_new();
ret = BN_set_word(bne, RSA_F4);
if(ret != 1) {
    BN_free(bne);
    return 0;
}

r = RSA_new();
ret = RSA_generate_key_ex(r, 2048, bne, NULL);
if(ret != 1){
    RSA_free(r);
    BN_free(bne);
    return 0;
}

//Now RSA keypair is generated, how to export it into a c array?

RSA_free(r);
BN_free(bne);
```

Comment: Research the BIO functions/offerings. Utilizing a memory BIO will probably do what you want (whatever it is).

Comment: d2i_RSAPublicKey and d2i_RSAPrivateKey write the DER encoding of the RSA Public/private key to an unsigned char array. Is that what you're looking for? If you want the PEM encoding then do as @WhozCraig says and use a mem bio.